Serverless deployment to new stage fails with non existent IAM Policy error
I have a serverless definition, that is working, when deploying to existing stages:
service: appcode-graphql

frameworkVersion: "3"
variablesResolutionMode: 20210326
useDotenv: true

unresolvedVariablesNotificationMode: error

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs20.x
  architecture: arm64
  region: ${opt:region, 'eu-central-1'}
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'app-dev'}
  stackTags:
    foo: bar
  tags:
    foo: bar

  logRetentionInDays: ${env:LOGRETENTION_IN_DAYS, 14}

  iam:
    deploymentRole: ${env:CFN_ROLE_ARN}
    role:
      permissionsBoundary: ${env:ROLEPERMISSIONS_BOUNDARY_ARN}

ROLEPERMISSIONS_BOUNDARY_ARN is defined as ROLEPERMISSIONS_BOUNDARY_ARN = arn:aws:iam::\${self:custom.accountId}:policy/acs/acs-boundary-policy 
Now I want to deploy that application to a new intermediate stage using a github workflow and receive the following error:
Error:
CREATE_FAILED: IamRoleLambdaExecution (AWS::IAM::Role)
Resource handler returned message: "Scope ARN: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx46559:policy/acs/acs-boundary-policy does not exist or is not attachable. (Service: Iam, Status Code: 404, Request ID: a3757afa-ed23-4b47-b959-893facec0558)" (RequestToken: 740e9309-b72c-6568-dfc9-340073e13fd8, HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)

Deploying to an already existing stage works. So here are my problems:

What is the permissionsBoundary explained in simple terms?
The policy/acs/acs-boundary-policy has not existed on that account according to my Cloudtrails lookups
Why is it failing and how can I fix it?


You say, that deploying to a new stage yields the error and on the other hand, that the role doesn't exist in "that account". Just to be sure: stages and accounts are different things. You can deploy to different stages, which all belong to the same account. When the role does not exist in the account, then it's expected, that it cannot be found; hence the error. If you deploy to different accounts, the role must exist in every of them.
